# Why won't javafx rectangles display their color when sizing to the parent container's getWidth/Height?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use rectangles as the background for text labels by putting them behind the VBox text in a StackPane, but when I try using the VBox's getWidth() or getHeight() values for the rectangle's size, the rectangle does not appear. I suppose I could

This works, displaying the blue rectangle behind the text, though not the size I want:

```
StackPane tadPane = new StackPane();
tadPane.setBorder(border);
Rectangle tadRec = new Rectangle();
VBox tadBox = new VBox();
Label totalXP = new Label("Total XP: ");
Label diff = new Label("Difficulty: ");
tadBox.getChildren().addAll(totalXP,diff);
tadRec.setWidth(50);
tadRec.setHeight(50);
tadRec.setFill(Color.BLUE);
tadPane.getChildren().addAll(tadRec,tadBox);
```

But this doesn't, the rectangle is not visible:

```
StackPane tadPane = new StackPane();
tadPane.setBorder(border);
Rectangle tadRec = new Rectangle();
VBox tadBox = new VBox();
Label totalXP = new Label("Total XP: ");
Label diff = new Label("Difficulty: ");
tadBox.getChildren().addAll(totalXP,diff);
tadRec.setWidth(tadBox.getWidth());
tadRec.setHeight(tadBox.getHeight());
tadRec.setFill(Color.BLUE);
tadPane.getChildren().addAll(tadRec,tadBox);
```

I can't understand why this would be happening. Raw numbers in the setWidth/Height work, but the getWidth/Height from the VBox should be returning numbers too if the labels with text are inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that at the time you retrieve the height and width, no layout pass has happened for the `VBox` so the size is still the initial one of 0 x 0.

You could use bindings to make the size update on a layout:

```
tadRec.widthProperty().bind(tadBox.widthProperty());
tadRec.heightProperty().bind(tadBox.heightProperty());
```

though it could be much simpler to simply apply a a background to the `VBox` instead of using a `Rectangle`:

```
tadBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
```